# Would the flag "wobble"?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, oscillators

If we take an imaginary situation where a flag made up of any material is held straight, parallel to a flowing current of *ideal* fluid, and leave it as soon as the current crosses it?

Actually, when I saw a fan turn on in the direction of a flag and that the flag starts wobbling in a kind of oscillatory motion. I'm not getting the reason behind this behaviour.

Comment: A google search for "flag instability" reveals that this is an area of current research in fluid dynamics. It would be great to have a good technical answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

A non flapping flag in a flowing air stream is in unstable equilibrium. Any small deviation from this position will be magnified and result in the oscillator flapping you observed.  It is similar to a pencil balanced on its point.

Comment: And does this mean that in the previous situation, the flag will remain straight as long as no disturbance occurs?

Comment: Yes, but that is mathematical abstraction that never hsppend.